# How to integrate by parts $n$ times with two variables?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

For one variable, it's true that
$$\int_a^b \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)dx=(-1)^n\int_a^bf(x)\frac{d^n}{dx^n}g(x)dx$$
if $f(a)g(a)=f(b)g(b)$. Question: it's true that:
$$\int_a^b\int_a^b \frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}(\frac{\partial^n}{\partial y^n}f(x,y))g(x,y)dxdy=(-1)^n\int_a^b \int_a^b f(x,y)\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}(\frac{\partial^n}{\partial y^n}g(x,y))dxdy$$
?

Comment: What do you think ? Have you tried applying the one variable rule and see what comes out ?

Comment: For one variable the identity is valid. I want to know if it's possible to extend this result for two variables.

Comment: I understand what the question is. What are **your own** thoughts/attempts? BTW looking at $n=2$ and dragging around the boundary terms I get \begin{align}
\int_a^b f''(x)g(x)\,dx&=-\int_a^b f'(x)g'(x)\,dx+f'(x)g(x)\Big|_a^b\\
&=\int_a^bf(x)g''(x)\,dx-f(x)g'(x)\Big|_a^b+f'(x)g(x)\Big|_a^b
\end{align} This makes me think that your one variable rule is not 100% correctly stated.

Comment: I tried with f=x-y and g=xy from 0 to 1 and it works with n=1. Maybe this example it's too simple tough.

Comment: Advice : think about the one-variable case again. I believe the boundary conditions need to be corrected for $n>1$. Probably best to assume $f,g$ and *all* their derivatives vanish at $a$ and $b$. Then go to the two variable case with $n=1$ and look at each of the *iterated* integrals individually. Then $n>1$ and so on.